# reading image from URL

Tags: java, http, groovy

If I execute the following Groovy code

```
URL url = new URL('http://glowstick.blisstunes.com/wp-content/plugins/rss-poster/cache/e1ebf_josh-wink.jpg')
ImageIO.read(url)
```

I get an exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1369)
```

But if I visit the URL in a browser the image displays. Is it because the HTTP request is being blocked because it doesn't look (from the headers) like it's coming from a browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787966/javax-imageio-iioexception-cant-get-input-stream-from-url should be the same problem

Comment: That code works for me in the Groovy Console... :-/

Comment: @tim_yates it works for me in the Groovy Console too. It also works when I run the app in the dev env. But it doesn't work in the Grails console of the app in production. I suspect dragons are to blame. Curiously, the `Toolkit` suggestion below does work.

Comment: @Don is the app server behind some sort of proxy? This seems to [suggest a different workaround](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=5355241#jive-message-5355242) if you want to stick with ImageIO

Comment: @tim_yates I don't think it's a proxy issue, because I can read other remote images without any problem. Just not this one for some reason.

Comment: @Don Odd.....  I currently blame Josh Wink...  But will keep thinking what it could be :-/

Comment: @tim_yates agreed, I don't know who he thinks he's impressing with those dreadlocks and wraparound shades. What he needs is a short back and sides and a pair of NHS specs. Kids today, pffff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
```

Comment: That seems to work, but unfortunately the code requires a `RenderedImage` rather than an `Image`. I've checked the implementation-type of this `image` and it's not a `RenderedImage`.

Comment: You can convert it to a `BufferedImage`!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code as reference. Do similar thing .

```
                    URL urlTemp ;
                    urlTemp = new URL( ContentUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection ycGetContent = null;
                    ycGetContent = (HttpURLConnection) urlTemp.openConnection();
                    ycGetContent.setDoOutput(true);
                    ycGetContent.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cooStr);
                    ycGetContent.connect();


                    BufferedInputStream bins =
                            new BufferedInputStream(ycGetContent.getInputStream());

                    FileOutputStream fout =
                            new FileOutputStream(lastWord);
                    int m = 0;

                    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024];



                    while ((m = bins.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(bytesIn, 0, m);
                    }
                    fout.close();
                    bins.close();

                    //System.out.println("File " +lastWord +" downloaded successfully ...\n\n ");   
                    LOG.info("File " +lastWord +" downloaded successfully");
```