# save downloaded Image to File

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to download an image from the Internet and save it to a file using the following method:

```
private BufferedImage saveImageLocally(String remoteImageURL, String imageType, File localImage) {

    URL url = new URL(remoteImageURL);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    ImageIO.write(image, imageType, localImage);
    return image;
}
```

However, I [ran into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742598/reading-image-from-url) with `ImageIO.read` which can be resolved by using:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
```

to read the image instead. However, I then can't use `ImageIO.write` to save the image to a file, because the first argument must be a `RenderedImage`.

Is there a way to save an `Image` (as opposed to a `BufferedImage`) to a file?

Comment: A file is a file, image or not, can't you just read it as a stream, and save it, what am I missing. For what it is worth, pls see my response below.

Answer (score 4):

```
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
```